# Can I do check spell in Android like it is done in Word?

Tags: android, spell-checking

If you type anything in MS Word, it does not do auto-complete or auto correct your word, it simply underlines the wrong words.

Can a similar functionality be achieved in Android.

I have searched many forums and sites, they all refer to check spell as either auto-complete or auto-correct.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Please check SpellCheckerSession out
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textservice/SpellCheckerSession.html

also, you should try to use Google before asking questions.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to mention. I'm using Android version 2.2 or level 8.

Comment: The link that you have posted is for API level 14.

Comment: Unfortunately Vote Down requires 125 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
String text = textView.getText();
if (!listOfAcceptableText.contains(text)) {
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(text);
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
    textView.setText(content);
}
```